# How do I get rich text to show up correctly in RSS Feed item in SXA?

Tags: sxa

I've got an RSS feed that has rich text in it's feed (i.e. paragraph markup, links, etc.) and when the feed is displayed on my website, the markup is not being rendered. [image: Example of markup not being rendered]

I am using the **Basic** theme in SXA.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This component uses external source. The problem here is that raw value from the source is displayed instead of HTML.

To change the way external content is displayed follow these steps:

1. Find following view file `Website\Views\Feed\Feed.cshtml`
2. Open file with your favourite text editor
3. Find following line

```html
<p class="feed-description">
    @item.Description
</p>
```

4. Change it to:

```html
<p class="feed-description">
    @{
        var description = new HtmlString(item.Description);
    }
    @description                            
</p>
```

Comment: That solved my problem. One additional question that I've got is about maintainability of this solution. How can I make this change in a way that upgrades won't be a problem?

Comment: It won't be a problem. Once you install a new version of **SXA** old view will be overwritten by the new one as default installation option is `Overwrite`. The problem should be fixed in the code so I would say you don't have worry about anything.